# Does the new comment @notification system take edits into consideration?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

If I post `Yeah, I agree` and then realize I forgot @Jeff and edit it to `@Jeff: yeah, I agree`, will Jeff be notified or not?

Also, what happens in the inverse scenario (I take a @name out with an edit) if the person hadn't been already notified?

Comment: Why not try it out?

Comment: *Yeah, I agree.* isn't worth a comment anyway. :)

Comment: @Georg: yeah, I agree [joke :D It was just an example ;)]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes.

You have a five minute grace period to edit your comments. After that time, it's locked and the script can run to send notifications on any @ matches.

If you click on the envelope for messages, you will note that comments posted on your posts will show up first. The @name notifications are on  a slight delay.

And if you need to comment:

> Yeah, I agree

Then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation :) And for your last comment, it was what I came up at the time as an example, I figured it didn't have to be a real, meaningful comment

Comment: Yeah, I agree. Especially about agreeing.

Comment: I agree with Marc.